# swift build faild due to "database is locked" in docker contianer?

Tags: swift, docker, mount

basically I am trying to learn swift in win7 using docker with following setup and steps:

1) physical machine running on win7

2) docker toolbox 1.12.5 window version installed in win7

3) open "Docker Quickstart Terminal" which is a MINGW64 console

4) in MINGW64 console,ran "docker pull swift" to pull a docker swift image

5) create container using "*docker run -it --hostname=value --privileged=true --net=host -v //d/dev/tools/docker/swift://swift:z --name swiftfun 24cc712c0763 /bin/bash*", which actually the volume mapping does not work. I can not create file in folder of my win7 host

swift version is :

```
root@value:/swift/PerfectTemplate/.build# swift -version
Swift version 3.0.2 (swift-3.0.2-RELEASE)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

linux container is :

```
root@value:/swift/PerfectTemplate/.build# cat /etc/*release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.2 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="16.04"
HOME_URL="http://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
VERSION_CODENAME=xenial
UBUNTU_CODENAME=xenial
```

6) then ran this in container "*mount -t cifs //10.x.x.xxx/D$/dev/tools/docker/swift /swift -o username=myusername,password=mypassword,noperm*" , this time works and I can see files in my win7 folder and can write files to win7 .

7) go to the folder "/swift" in container and pull code from git as shown in this link http://perfect.org/docs/gettingStarted.html . I can see files/folders created in win7 folder

8) in container, go to folder "PerfectTemplate" and ran swift build , it failed with following message :

...

```
Cloning https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-Thread.git
HEAD is now at aee3b32 Cleanup
Resolved version: 2.0.9
<unknown>:0: error: unable to attach DB: unable to initialize database (database
 is locked)
error: exit(1): /usr/bin/swift-build-tool -f /swift/PerfectTemplate/.build/debug
.yaml
```

...

there is a file build.db created in my win7 folder            `D:\dev\tools\docker\swift\PerfectTemplate\.build\build.db`
and the file size remains 0 byte

following is verbose info from building:

```
/usr/bin/swiftc --driver-mode=swift -I /usr/lib/swift/pm -L /usr/lib/swift/pm -l
PackageDescription /swift/PerfectTemplate/Packages/PerfectThread-2.0.9/Package.s
wift -fileno 4
/usr/bin/swift-build-tool -f /swift/PerfectTemplate/.build/debug.yaml -v
<unknown>:0: error: unable to attach DB: unable to initialize database (database
 is locked)
error: exit(1): /usr/bin/swift-build-tool -f /swift/PerfectTemplate/.build/debug
.yaml -v
```

if I use linux local folder for building code then everything is working fine .the size of build.db changes . does it have anything to do with mounted drive using //ip/drive ? 
how do I resolve ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK, it seems that sqlite is not tolerate to mapped windows folder in containers. I tried mapping folders using both //ip/folder approach and virtualbox shared folder approach . none of them works. and seems it has something to do with winLockFile,please check link below

http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/SQLite3-database-on-windows-network-drive-and-unreliable-connection-td75875.html

https://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html

I also checked source code of swift package manager , it seems there is no way of adding options to swift-build-tool as part of "swift build" command